# Byref New Object. Is it okay top pass New Object as "byref"

Tags: vb.net

Below I tried to do an Example:

```
Public Function UserData(ByVal UserDN As String) As DataTable
    Dim myTable As DataTable = UserData_Table()
    Dim dr As DataRow

    dr = myTable.NewRow()
    SplitOU2(UserDN, dr("OUDN"), dr("Organisation"), New Object)
    dr("UserDN") = UserDN

    myTable.Rows.Add(dr)

    Return myTable
End Function
```

Below is the called method:

```
Friend Sub SplitOU2(ByVal inDN As String, ByRef OUDN As Object, ByRef Organisation As Object, ByRef VerksamhetTyp As Object)
```

By doing this I can skip to declare the in this example "useless" variable 
`Dim VerksamhetTyp as Object = ""`.

Perhaps it looks a little ugly but to have to declare unused variables can also be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:** Check whether or not the method really needs those parameters to be `ByRef`. Also check that you really don't care about anything it does to the parameters. After scrupulous checking, it's okay to do this - nothing "bad" will happen in terms of the CLR, because it's just a compiler trick under the hood.

Well, VB (unlike C#) will let you do this. Behind the scenes it's *effectively* creating a new variable and passing it by reference - after all, it has to for the method to be called properly. However, I'd say this is *usually* a bad idea. The point of `ByRef` is that you use the value after it's been set within the method.

Do you *really* need all those parameters to be `ByRef` in the first place? If you find yourself doing this a lot for a particular method, you could always write a wrapper method which called the original one, but didn't have the `ByRef` parameters itself.

(I usually find that methods with a lot of `ByRef` parameters indicate *either* a lack of understanding of reference types in .NET, *or* that the parameters should be encapsulated in their own type.)

Having said all of this, it's not *always* incorrect to ignore the value of a `ByRef` argument after calling the method. For example, if you just want to know whether or not some text can be parsed as an integer, then using `Int32.TryParse` is reasonable - but only the return value  is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that I consider to use this has to do with that the method has even more parameters and that different operation overloads gets the same signature ….
The fact that it works is quite fun and somthing I became awarae óff by chance ...